# printing text at any position on the screen

Tags: c

I would like to know how to print texts at different positions using C program. I would like to split the screen into four quarters and I would like to print different set of values in each quarter.

For Example: 
            Data X will be printed in Quarter 1 and Data Y will be printed in Quarter 2,etc.

How do I achieve that on Linux platform?

Thanks,

Comment: on which platform ? unix, windows, other ?

Comment: Your best bet is using some curses-derived library (ncurses, pdcurses) to handle that stuff.

Comment: "Position" isn't a well-defined part of C. You have to say more precisely what you mean.

Comment: Will this program run in text only mode, or are there multiple GUI windows?

Comment: @JoshPetitt: It's text only mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under linux the easiest way is to use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). It's GNU software, reliable and opensource. Check the links on the page.
You could also look at [libyui](http://www.slideshare.net/hedgehogpainter/3-uis-for-the-price-of-one-code), the toolkit used to develop YAST (opensuse), downloadable on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libyui/). I never used it but it would allow you to generate console UI and GUI (GTK+ and Qt) ...
Just to be complete, you may also use a [screen multiplexer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549/tmux-vs-gnu-screen), but this is out of the scope of your question.